# Implementing pure virtual function in the abstract class - is there any use of it?

Tags: c++, abstract-class, virtual-functions

I just noticed that I could have an implementation of a pure virtual function in the abstract class itself. GCC doesn't complain. Is there any use of such implementation? Can anybody use it?

```
class AbstractClass
{
    virtual void PureVirtualFunction() = 0;
};

void AbstractClass::PureVirtualFunction() //Is there any use of this implementation?
{
    cout << "I am inside pure virtual function of AbstractClass" << endl;
}

class DerivedClass : public AbstractClass
{
    public:
        void PureVirtualFunction();
};

void DerivedClass::PureVirtualFunction()
{
    cout << "I am inside pure virtual function of DerivedClass" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use it to provide a default implementation which is accessible to derived classes.

One possible use is "Dear derived class authors, this virtual function is *very important* and I want to be sure that you know what you're doing with it. I will provide a default implementation, but you *must* use it explicitly." This would be done like this:

```
class AbstractClass
{
public:
    virtual void PureVirtualFunction() = 0;
};

void AbstractClass::PureVirtualFunction() //Is there any use of this implementation?
{
    cout << "I am inside pure virtual function of AbstractClass" << endl;
}

class DerivedClass : public AbstractClass
{
    public:
        void PureVirtualFunction();
};

void DerivedClass::PureVirtualFunction()
{
    AbstractClass::PureVirtualFunction();
}
```

Comment: This won't work since PureVirtualFunction is private.

Answer (score 1):

You can call it from `DerivedClass` implementation for example (if `AbstractClass::PureVirtualFunction` is not private):

```
void DerivedClass::PureVirtualFunction()
{
    AbstractClass::PureVirtualFunction();
    cout << "I am inside pure virtual function of DerivedClass" << endl;
}
```

Or even if it's private you can call it from `AbstractClass` itself:

```
class AbstractClass
{
    virtual void PureVirtualFunction() = 0;

public:
    void CallPureVirtualFunction() {
        AbstractClass::PureVirtualFunction();
    }
};

DerivedClass().CallPureVirtualFunction();

I am inside pure virtual function of AbstractClass
```